# Not able to verify a JWT token on Nextjs app

Tags: typescript, next.js, jwt

I'm trying to verify a JWT token in Nextjs but I'm getting this error like below

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
```

below is the code that I'm using

```
useEffect(() => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("jqToken") || "";
    let result: any = "";
    try {
      result = jwt.verify(token, "SECRETEKEY");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, "ERR");
    }
    console.log("first", result);
  }, []);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I doubt that JWTs are to be verified on the client. You would want to make a call to your API to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by creating a file at root by naming it "verifyToken.ts"
then write the code below

```
 import jwt, { JwtPayload, Secret } from 'jsonwebtoken';

export const verifyToken = (token: string, secret: Secret): JwtPayload | null => {
    try {

        // Verify the token using the provided secret key
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret) as JwtPayload;
        console.log(decoded)
        return decoded;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)

        return null;
    }
};
```

Then the problem solved

Comment: Will try this one

Comment: No not working getting the same error again "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object".